# Non-equilibrium CPCM for Orca Absorption Spectra

Tags: orca, implicit-solvent, nonequilibrium

I run into this article<sup>[1]</sup> in which they figure out that if you want to correctly simulate electronic spectra you have to consider the *non-equilibrium* solvation.

I've made research into the documentation of Orca, but I couldn't find anything about how set this type of calculation.

I'm using CPCM n-hexane. Does someone know how to include non-equilibrium implicit solvation effects in Orca?

**References**:

1. Cammi, R.; Corni, S.; Mennucci, B.; Tomasi, J. [Electronic excitation energies of molecules in solution: State specific and linear response methods for nonequilibrium continuum solvation models.](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1867373) *J. Chem. Phys.* **2005,** *122* (10), 104513. DOI: 10.1063/1.1867373.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ORCA by default uses non-equilibrium solvation for single-point TDDFT calculations, and equilibrium solvation when the TDDFT gradient is requested (e.g. when doing excited state geometry optimization, numerical frequency and molecular dynamics calculations). Thus in most cases it is not necessary to explicitly request for equilibrium/non-equilibrium solvation, as the default choice is usually the correct one. If it is desired to override the default behavior, one can use the CPCMEQ keyword in the %tddft block. For example, the following input block calculates 5 non-equilibrium solvated states, regardless of whether the gradient is requested:

```
%tddft
nroots 5
cpcmeq false
end
```

Contrarily, setting CPCMEQ to true requests equilibrium solvation.